# getting error "Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. " when populate data in grid

Tags: c#, grid, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting this error while i am trying to populate data on grid please help me    out .. i tried my best

I am not using model class , rather i am using datamodel.edmx, still why i am getting the errors

I am using MVC 5

My Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

WifyConnectEntities wc = new WifyConnectEntities();

IEnumerable<Connected_User> connected = wc.Connected_User;

return View(connected);
}
```

My View

```
@model IEnumerable<MarketingEngine.Connected_User>

@using System.Web.Mvc.Html

@using GridMvc.Html

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Welcome @Convert.ToString(Session["BusinessUser"])</h2>

@Html.ActionLink("Refresh The List", "Refresh")

<html>
<head>

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Gridmvc.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js")"></script>

<div style="width:500px;">



@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns => 
{
columns.Add(c => c.User_ID).Titled("User_ID");
columns.Add(c => c.Session_Start).Titled("Session_Start").Filterable(true);
columns.Add(c => c.Duration).Titled("Duration");
}).WithPaging(3).Sortable(true)
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check there is this in web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```